# SQL with most current position and weight

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following problem. I have a SQL Server database with two tables.

The first table has columns `PositionName`, `date` and `AnimalName`, and the second table has columns `Weight`, `date` and `AnimalName`

Now because an animal moves around and I need to evaluate these rows of data I store every new position or every new weight as a new row.

But now I want to get the current position of the animal and the current weight that it has got. how can i handle this?

Example Data

Table Position

```
A, 23.02.2015, ABC
B, 28.02.2015, ABC
```

Table Weight

```
A, 3.09, 22.02.2015, ABC
B, 2.3, 23.03.2015, ABC
```

What I want is this

Table WeightPosition

```
Name   Weight   Position
ABC      2.3       B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.animalname, w.weight, p.positionname
  from position p
  join weight w
    on p.animalname = w.animalname
 where p.dt = (select max(x.dt) from position x where x.animalname = p.animalname)
   and w.dt = (select max(x.dt) from weight x where x.animalname = w.animalname)
```

(change field names as needed)

**Fiddle test:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31358/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT an.AnimalName, w.Weight, p.Position FROM
(SELECT AnimalName FROM Positions UNION SELECT AnimalName FROM Weights) an
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Weight FROM Weights where AnimalName = an.AnimalName ORDER BY Date desc) w
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 Position FROM Positions where AnimalName = an.AnimalName ORDER BY Date desc) p
```